# Is it possible to support TLSv1.3+ on Android API <20 by using a 3rd party library?

Tags: ssl, android

I have to support an Android device that uses Android API <20 (KitKat and older). We use AWS for our APIs and want to support TLSv1.3 and beyond, but these devices may not be upgraded for some time. Android API <20 doesn't natively support TLSv1.3+, but is it possible to use a third-party TLS library to support TLSv1.3? If so, how? Googling around has not turned up anything apart from "upgrade your device".

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for recommendations of third-party libraries on Stack Overflow is considered to be off-topic. That being said, I am not aware of anything that meets your description.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok.. thanks for the advice.. i have re-worded my question to make it less "off topic"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this using the [Conscrypt Library](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) which goes all the way back to Android 2.x

You can reference that library and then make use of it by:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think  Android device will support TLS 1.3 because TLS 1.3 is too new and almost all the browser cannot support TLS 1.3. The most of theme they use the older version TLS 1.2, TLS 1.2 compatible with all the IDE and Web platforms such as chrome or firefox. Also TLS 1.3 is very hard to create because there is almost no info about encryption with TLS 1.3.

Comment: Per https://caniuse.com/#feat=tls1-3 Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera all support 1.3, and Edge will once it turns into Chromium, currently covering 80% of users. That's 'most' in my book. Of course when connecting to an older _server_ it doesn't get used.

Comment: "TLS 1.3 is too new" False. "almost all the browser cannot support TLS 1.3" False. "there is almost no info about encryption with TLS 1.3" False.